# Detect file mode changes on pre-commit hook

Tags: git, githooks

I want to be able to know if someone changed the file mode on some scripts and display a warning to make sure that it was intended and not a silly mistake.

Currently I try to do something like this on my pre-commit hook:

```
mode_changed=$(git diff --summary | grep "mode")
#echo "mode change is $mode_changed"
if ! [[ -z "$mode_changed" ]]; then
  echo "Warning Files Modes Changed"
fi
```

This works if the files are not staged for commit, but as soon as I call git commit -a, then the previous script no longer works, the return value in the variable mode_changed is always empty. Is there another way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the staged differences, use

```
git diff --summary --staged
```

(or `--cached`, which is a synonym for `--staged`).

You can also simplify your condition a bit:

```
if [ -n "$mode_changed" ]; then
```